# Can you change skins with the same character?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have a skin in Minecraft and I want to change it. Is it possible to change it on a single character?

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely. Visit the Minecraft website, [log in](http://www.minecraft.net/login), and you can select your skin as much as you like. You can log in to a server with a different skin every 10 minutes if you like. The skin is fetched on log-in; changing it on the site will not change it on your game character until you log out and back in to the server.

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to set a skin per server or map if that is what you are asking. It is per Minecraft account, so as Myrddin mentions you can change it as often as you like, but it will not automagically be this skin on that server and another skin on the server over there.